# Is a Nuget Package considered an API?

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I'm trying to include writing a nuget package on my resume and I want the terminology to be correct.  From my understanding, a nuget package is an API, but I don't want to appear foolish if this is incorrect.  Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: Nuget package you have written exposes some public API (I assume, otherwise why would you create it) which can be used by clients, but itself is not one. If you want to reference the creation of nuget in your resume just write "created library for ..." or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

No, a NuGet package is not an API

[NuGet documentation | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/#:%7E:text=NuGet%20is%20the%20package%20manager,these%20libraries%20as%20%22packages%22.)

> NuGet is the package manager for . NET. It enables developers to create, share, and consume useful . NET libraries. NuGet client tools provide the ability to produce and consume these libraries as "packages".

The Nuget package manager uses APIs to publish and download .Net libraries, but a NuGet package itself is just a bunch of .Net libraries.  These packages may consume or expose APIs, but the package itself isn't an API.

You might be thinking of the NuGet Server API
[Overview of the NuGet Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview)

> The NuGet Server API is a set of HTTP endpoints that can be used to download packages, fetch metadata, publish new packages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**No the package manager is not an API**

If you are talking about NuGet Server API, then yes that is an API, but if your question is in general terms of NuGet it is just a package manager for .NET which uses a bunch of .NET libratries.

More on NuGet Server API :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview

NuGet package manager :-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/

Comment: But the OP is explicitly asking about Nuget packages, not about Nuget itself or the Nuget Server API.

Comment: @jps Yes, but they are possibly confusing the different aspects.